# DB changes doesn't reflect on Diagram

Tags: sql-server, database, diagram

I'm working on SQL Server, I have edited some of DB tables and their relationships but when I generate the diagram and added the tables, it doesn't show the changes in the diagram.
Even the changes appear if I expand the table for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Right click on diagram and choose `remove table from diagram`.
2. Right click in the white space and choose `Add Table`.

This should show new diagram.

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work. also I tried to refresh and disconnect and reconnect. Nothing worked.

Comment: Create a copy of database and check there ? It's not a solution but a way to narrow down problem

Comment: Actually the solution was silly. I just closed sql server and restart it.

Comment: Thanks for posting it :)